# Executing CONCAT statement in stored procedures doesn't work

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, concatenation, prepared-statement

I have two tables, a base table with all sorts of information about a value 'tconst' which is also the primary key, and another table which links from 'nconst' to multiple 'tconst' values under the name of 'titleId'.

---Base table 'titlebasics'

| tconst | titleType | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tt0000009 | movie | ... |
| tt0000147 | movie | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

---extra info table 'knownfortitles'

| id | nconst | titleOrder | titleId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nm0000001 | 1 | tt0050419 |
| 2 | nm0000001 | 2 | tt0053137 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The 'problem' is that some values in `knownfortitles.titleId` are not present in `titlebasics.tconst`. I want to create a stored procedures where I can pass along the names of the two tables and of the two corresponding columns as paramaters. This procedure would first check if there are indeed values in the second table that are not present in the first, and if so, add a column to the second table named `is_in_<base_table_name>`. Then it would subsequently update this column with boolean values for each row in the second table. I want this done in a stored procedure, because I have a lot of tables with this exact problem, and I want to be able to use this procedure instead of writing the same code over and over again with different values. However, I'm getting errors when trying to call my procedure that I can't seem to fix.

As a stored procedure, this is where I've stranded.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CheckValueExistsInBaseTable`(
    IN checkedTable VARCHAR(100),
    IN referencedBaseTable VARCHAR(100),
    IN checkedCol VARCHAR(100),
    IN referencedCol VARCHAR(100)
    )
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_column_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'is_in_baseTable';
    DECLARE sql_statement1 VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT 'SELECT NULL;';
    DECLARE sql_statement2 VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT 'SELECT NULL;';
    
    SET @new_column_name  = CONCAT('is_in_',referencedBaseTable);
    
    -- Add new column to checked table if it doesn't exist
    SET @sql_statement1 = CONCAT('IF (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM ', checkedTable, ' 
    WHERE ', checkedCol, ' NOT IN (SELECT ', referencedCol, ' FROM ', referencedBaseTable, ')) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) = 1
THEN 
    ALTER TABLE ', checkedTable, ' ADD ', @new_column_name, ' BOOL;
ELSE 
    SELECT NULL;
END IF');
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_statement1;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
    
    -- Update is_in_referencedBaseTable column in checked table
    SET @sql_statement2 = CONCAT('UPDATE ', checkedTable, ' SET ', 
        @new_column_name, ' = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ', 
        referencedBaseTable, ' WHERE ', referencedBaseTable, '.', 
        referencedCol, ' = ', checkedTable, '.', checkedCol, ') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END');
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql_statement2;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
END
```

This gives me one of the following errors, no matter what I try to change.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

or

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
> SELECT 1
> FROM knownfortitles
> WHERE titleId NOT' at line 1

I've also created test procedures to check what parts could be the issue, but both work perfectly fine, which leaves me even more confused. This first one just returns what I've put in my `CONCAT` to see if there are any syntax errors there.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
    IN checkedTable VARCHAR(100),
    IN referencedBaseTable VARCHAR(100),
    IN checkedCol VARCHAR(100),
    IN referencedCol VARCHAR(100),
    IN new_column_name VARCHAR (100)
)
BEGIN
-- Declaring the variable and assigning the value
declare myvar VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE new_column_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'is_in_baseTable';
SET @new_column_name  = CONCAT('is_in_',referencedBaseTable);
 
SET myvar =  CONCAT('IF (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM ', checkedTable, ' 
    WHERE ', checkedCol, ' NOT IN (SELECT ', referencedCol, ' FROM ', referencedBaseTable, ')) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) = 1
THEN 
    ALTER TABLE ', checkedTable, ' ADD ', @new_column_name, ' BOOL;
ELSE 
    SELECT NULL;
END IF');

-- Printing the value to the console
SELECT concat(myvar) AS Variable;
END
```

This procedure gives the next result:

```
IF (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM knownfortitles 
    WHERE titleId NOT IN (SELECT tconst FROM titlebasics)) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 ) = 1
 THEN 
    ALTER TABLE knownfortitles ADD is_in_titlebasics BOOL;
 ELSE 
    SELECT NULL;
 END IF
```

This code is correct, and I know this because I used the second procedure below that utilizes this exact block of code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test2`()
BEGIN    
    IF (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM knownfortitles
        WHERE titleId NOT IN (SELECT tconst FROM titlebasics)) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) = 1
    THEN 
        ALTER TABLE knownfortitles ADD is_in_titlebasics BOOL;
    ELSE 
        SELECT NULL;
    END IF;
END
```

This procedures adds the column `is_in_titlebasics` to table `knownfortitles` , which is what I want to happen, so that's good. At this point, I'm completely lost and don't know why my actual stored procedure isn't working, given it's basically a combination of the last two procedures. I'm disregarding the second part of what I want my stored procedure to do for now because the errors I'm getting seem to refer to the first `CONCAT` statement as the issue.

I'm hoping the issue is something extremely obvious that I'm just overlooking. Any help is welcomed, thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot run anonymous code blocks eg if...end if  outwith stored programs..something which you have proved yourself by dropping the generated code into a procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to P. Salmon, I learned the issue was running an `IF ... THEN` statement through a prepared statement. This is not possible. After some tinkering, I came up with the following procedure, which works exactly like I want. I hope I can help some folks that have an analogous issue to what I was struggling with.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `<schema>`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`Setupinfolab`@`%` PROCEDURE `CheckValueExistsInBaseTable`(
    IN checkedTable VARCHAR(100),
    IN referencedBaseTable VARCHAR(100),
    IN checkedCol VARCHAR(100),
    IN referencedCol VARCHAR(100)
    )
BEGIN
    SET @checkedTable = checkedTable;
    SET @referencedBaseTable = referencedBaseTable;
    SET @checkedCol = checkedCol;
    SET @referencedCol = referencedCol;
    SET @new_column_name  = CONCAT('is_in_', referencedBaseTable);
    
    -- Check if there are indeed values in checkedCol that are not present in referencedCol
    SET @query1 = CONCAT('
        SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM ',@checkedTable,'
            WHERE ',@checkedCol,' NOT IN (SELECT ',@referencedCol,' FROM ',@referencedBaseTable,')) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
            INTO @proceed');
        
    -- Adding the boolean column
    SET @query2 = CONCAT('
        ALTER TABLE ',@checkedTable,' ADD ',@new_column_name,' BOOL;');
    
    -- Inserting boolean values in new column according to presence in referencedCol
    SET @query3 = CONCAT('
        UPDATE ',@checkedTable,' SET ',@new_column_name,' = (
            CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                SELECT * 
                FROM ',@referencedBaseTable,' 
                WHERE ',@referencedBaseTable,'.',@referencedCol,' = ',@checkedTable,'.',@checkedCol,')
            THEN true ELSE false END
            ) WHERE id<>0;');
    
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query1;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    
    IF @proceed = 1
    THEN 
        PREPARE stmt2 FROM @query2;
        EXECUTE stmt2;
        PREPARE stmt3 FROM @query3;
        EXECUTE stmt3;
        SELECT CONCAT(@new_column_name,' column added to table ', @checkedTable,'.') 
            AS 'Message: Done';
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'All values are present in base table. Adding column is thus unnecessary.' 
            AS 'Message: UNNECESSARY';
    END IF;
    
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
;
```

I'd like to note, however, that I haven't added a `TRY ... CATCH` or anything to prevent the procedure from throwing an error yet. This is just the bare minimum to make it work.

Calling the procedure

```
CALL CheckValueExistsInBaseTable(
    'knownfortitles',
    'titlebasics',
    'titleId',
    'tconst'
    );
```

Returns either a message confirmation:

> "Message: Done"
>
> ---
>
> "`is_in_titlebasics` column added to table `knownfortitles`."

or a message warning:

> "Message: UNNECESSARY"
>
> ---
>
> "All values are present in base table. Adding column is thus unnecessary."

Only in the first case, a `TINYINT(1)` column is added, as desired.